# How to use maven which is installed in windows, at windows subsystem for Linux

Tags: java, maven, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had installed my maven at windows 10. Java-Home and M2-Home is set and both are referenced at the Path-Variable. 
When I do a check (mvn --version) it works at cmd. If I start mvn --version at WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) there is an Error:

"Fehler: Hauptklasse org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden"
so the error-message says, that the org.codehaus.plexus.classwords.launcher.Launcher can't be found or loaded.

Does anybody have any tip for me?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you installed maven on top of Ubuntu? Try to install maven in ubuntu using **sudo apt install -y maven** command.

Comment: No, beacause i do not want to install it on Ubuntu. I want to use the one which is installed at windows 10. If i need to install maven a second time is there a chance to use the same config?

Comment: have you eventually found the solution for this? I am hitting the same issue

Comment: I have the opposite problem and cannot get rid of the behaviour that you guys apparently want. 
I do have a maven installed in Ubuntu, but when I run commands that include mvn via wsl ("from the outside), it never uses the mvn installed inside ubuntu. 
E.g. `wsl which mvn` points to the "outside maven" at `/mnt/c/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin/mvn`. 
When I run `which mvn` inside Ubuntu manually, it correctly states `/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/mvn`. 
Weird.